# Bitwise operator in Apache Drill

Tags: bitwise-operators, apache-drill

I'm considering using Apache Drill as query engine for existing system. Some columns of the table represent multiple values encoded as Int which allows to do e.g.
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM options WHERE opt_a & 2 > 0`. It seems like Drill does not have bitwise operators implemented. Any word on this feature to be added in near future or any ideas how to extend Drill in easy way to support this?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like these functions should be available, they just aren't provided with the java/c syntax. Providing this would probably involve modifying the parser, although I'm not sure if this would conform to the SQL spec.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-923

If something you need is missing, developing functions in Drill is pretty straightforward. There are a few idiosyncrasies to the UDF interface. Here is a list of some dos and don'ts from the docs:

To leverage Java’s just-in-time (JIT) compiler for maximum speed, you need to adhere to some basic rules.

- Do not use imports. Instead, use the fully qualified class name as required by the Google Guava API packaged in Apache Drill and as shown in "Step 3: Declare input parameters".
- Manipulate the ValueHolders classes, for example VarCharHolder and IntHolder, as structs by calling helper methods, such as getStringFromVarCharHolder and toStringFromUTF8 as shown in "Step 5: Implement the eval() function".
- Do not call methods such as toString because this causes serious problems.
- Use the maven-source-plugin to compile the sources and classes JAR files.

Here is a page from the docs that covers writing a simple function:
https://drill.apache.org/docs/develop-custom-functions-introduction/

If you have any questions feel free to hit up the dev or user mailing lists. People are generally more responsive there than on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be as easy as creating a Simple function (following documentation) that would return true/false and used in WHERE clause?